# Assert that arrays are equal in Visual Studio 2008 test framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Is there an easy way to check in a unit test that two arrays are equal (that is, have the same number of elements, and each element is the same?).

In Java, I would use `assertArrayEquals (foo, bar);`, but there seems to be no equivalent for C#. I tried `Assert.AreEqual(new string[]{"a", "b"}, MyFunc("ab"));`, but even though the function returns an array with "a", "b" the check still fails

This is using Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite, with the built-in unit test framework.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

It's `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`, see also the [documentation for CollectionAssert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Just keep in mind the following, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194966/mstest-collectionassert-areequivalent-failed-the-expected-collection-contains the objects may be compared explicitly with `object.Equals` and the `IEqualityComparer<T>` may have to be defined in order to get passed a failed assertion.

Comment: I wish this gave more detailed messages when it failed. "Different number of elements" and "Element at index 0 do not match" are slightly useless. *What are they then?!*

Comment: `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` (available from Visual Studio 2010) gives more informative results. For instance, when the number of elements differ, the message states the expected and the actual number of elements

Answer (score 26):

Class1.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        Array arr1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        public Array getArray()
        {
            return arr1;
        }
    }
}
```

ArrayEqualTest.cs:

```
        [TestMethod()]
        public void getArrayTest()
        {
            Class1 target = new Class1(); 
            Array expected = new []{1,2,3,4,5}; 
            Array actual;
            actual = target.getArray();
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            //Assert.IsTrue(expected.S actual, "is the test results");
        }
```

Test Success,found the error:

```
   CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 3 do not match.)
```

Comment: Damn I've downvoted this answer by accident and now I cannot undo my downvote - I got "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" :(

Comment: This answer doesn't look better than the one from year before it.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 3.5, perhaps consider `Assert.IsTrue(foo.SequenceEqual(bar));` - it won't tell you at what index it differs, though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a slightly longer way of doing it...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arr1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var arr2 = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 4, 5 };

    Console.WriteLine("Arrays are equal: {0}", equals(arr1, arr2));
}

private static bool equals(IEnumerable arr1, IEnumerable arr2)
{

    var enumerable1 = arr1.OfType<object>();
    var enumerable2 = arr2.OfType<object>();

    if (enumerable1.Count() != enumerable2.Count())
        return false;

    var iter1 = enumerable1.GetEnumerator();
    var iter2 = enumerable2.GetEnumerator();

    while (iter1.MoveNext() && iter2.MoveNext())
    {
        if (!iter1.Current.Equals(iter2.Current))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```