# C# - serializing list works, but deserializing returns empty list

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an odd problem with XML deserialization in C#. Serializing the object works as expected, but deserializing makes the list-valued attribute `Files` empty.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace Converter
{
   [Serializable]
   [XmlRoot("userinput")]
   public class Input
   {

      [XmlArray("files")]
      [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(FilePair), ElementName = "filepair")]
      public List<FilePair> Files;


      public Input()
      { }

   }
}
```

and the element:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Converter
{
   [Serializable]
    public class FilePair
    {
        [XmlElement("file1")]
        public string File1;

        [XmlElement("file2")]
        public string File2;

        public FilePair() { }

    }

    public enum FileSource { Foo, Bar };
}
```

and a sample XML:

```
<userinput>
   <files>
      <filepair>
         <file1>foo</file1>
         <file2>bar</file2>
      </filepair>
      <filepair>
         <file1>foo</file1>
         <file2>bar</file2>
      </filepair>
   </files>
</userinput>
```

Comment: check this one may this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517064/deserializing-a-generic-list-returns-null

Comment: when I try this, I get "The XML element 'file1' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element." - is this your actual code? presumably you mean `[XmlElement("file2")]` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell No I anonymized a bit as I am not comfortable posting actual code from work. The second "file1" should read "file2". My bad, but not the Problem in the original code. I edited my answer to correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take your code, fix the `[XmlElement("file2")]`, and use:

```
    var xml = @"<userinput>
<files>
  <filepair>
     <file1>foo</file1>
     <file2>bar</file2>
  </filepair>
  <filepair>
     <file1>foo</file1>
     <file2>bar</file2>
  </filepair>
</files>
</userinput>";
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var obj = (Input)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Input)).Deserialize(reader);
        foreach(var file in obj.Files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{file.File1}, {file.File2}");
        }
    }
```

then: it works. The output is:

```
foo, bar
foo, bar
```

So: whatever the problem is: you've fixed it when creating your minimal sample.

So *now* the question becomes: what is different between your minimal sample and your real code? Answer that, and you'll answer the question for yourself.

Comment: Well that sucks I guess. Ok I will see how much I can reduce the code so it still doesn't work, and get back.

Comment: It turns out what is actually wrong is my test code. I am checking Equivalency with CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent which leads me to believe there are 0 elements in the deserialized list, which is not true. Instead, I think the comparison works by reference as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821628/collectionassert-areequivalent-failing-cant-figure-out-why and I need to implement an equality test or something. Thanks for double checking the code. That error message was a little misleading. After implementing Equals and hashcode on FilePair, the test works.

Comment: @kutschkem learning point then: if you'd just taken an extra 3 minutes to turn your example (which was good - no complaints there) into a *runnable* example, you'd have seen that it didn't exhibit the problem :)