# CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, collections, nunit

I cant seem to find out why I am getting this error as the `actual` and `expected` are returning the same values at index 0 and have exactly the same properties. what could be the possible cause of this problem? I've looked around but cant find any viable solution as of yet.

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void unSortedLeadsTest()
        {
            List<CustomerLead> expected = new List<CustomerLead>();
            List<CustomerLead> actual = new List<CustomerLead>();
            CustomerLeads target = new CustomerLeads(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            string xml = "C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/potentialcustomers.xml"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value

            actual = target.unSortedLeads(xml);
            CustomerLead lead = new CustomerLead()
            {
                FirstName = actual[0].FirstName,
                LastName=actual[0].LastName,
                EmailAddress=actual[0].EmailAddress

            };
            CustomerLead lead1 = new CustomerLead()
            {
                FirstName = actual[1].FirstName,
                LastName = actual[1].LastName,
                EmailAddress = actual[1].EmailAddress

            };
            CustomerLead lead2 = new CustomerLead()
            {
                FirstName = actual[2].FirstName,
                LastName = actual[2].LastName,
                EmailAddress = actual[2].EmailAddress

            };

            target.addressList.Add(lead);
            target.addressList.Add(lead1);
            target.addressList.Add(lead2);


            foreach (CustomerLead i in target.addressList) {

            expected.Add(lead);
            }

            // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }
```

**Edit:** Ive attempted to override Equals but am struggling: any Ideas how I might acheive this?

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;

           CustomerLead leadsequal = obj as CustomerLead;
           if ((Object)leadsequal == null)
                return false;
            else
               return Equals( leadsequal);
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at this thread, in case its relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724524/cannot-compare-lists-in-unittests/19724980#19724980

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that this:

```
foreach (CustomerLead i in target.addressList) {
    expected.Add(lead);
}
```

should be:

```
foreach (CustomerLead i in target.addressList) {
    expected.Add(i);
}
```

Otherwise you're adding the same reference three times.

It's not really clear to me what you're trying to test, mind you... and you may well be fine with just:

```
List<CustomerLead> expected = target.addressList.ToList();
```

... along with a `using` directive of:

```
using System.Linq;
```

EDIT: Additionally, for two objects to be considered equal just because they've got the same properties, you'll need to override `object.Equals(object)` and ideally implement `IEquatable<CustomerLead>` too. By default, you just get reference equality - any two distinct objects are considered non-equal, even if every property is equal.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've changed the `lead` to `i`in the foreach but still getting the same error. also `.ToList` doesnt appear for `target.addressList`

Comment: @user2708073: See my edit. As for why `ToList()` doesn't appear - you'd need `using System.Linq;` Of course we don't know the type of `targetList`, which doesn't help...

Comment: Thanks how do I go about implementing IEquatable? and overriding the equas(objecT)?

Comment: @user2708073: Well what have you *tried* when it comes to overriding `Equals`? What did you get stuck on?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet because Im not sure how this will work. because I already have `List<CustomerLead> expected = new List<CustomerLead>();`
            `List<CustomerLead> actual = new List<CustomerLead>();` How Will I implement Equatable? and Im not sure what I will use to override Equals. Ive done some reading but not sure I fully understand. Also, there were no examples for Collections.

Comment: @user2708073: It's not about collections - it's about making one `CustomerLead` equal to another, based on their properties. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Im still not quite understanding how to do this. Can you see my edit? thanks!

Comment: Would It be useful if I provided the class I was testing?

Comment: @user2708073: Your `Equals` method should be comparing each property... and you'll need to override `GetHashCode` too. I don't really want to go any further in this comment thread - it sounds like the kind of thing where you'd be best off finding a colleague who can help you in person.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, as others have pointed out, you have to correctly implement `Equals` method.

```cs
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    CustomerLead other = obj as CustomerLead;
    if ((Object)other == null)
        return false;

    // here you need to compare two objects
    // below is just example implementation

    return this.FirstName == other.FirstName
        && this.LastName == other.LastName
        && this.EmailAddress == other.EmailAddress;
}
```

Secondly, in your test method, you must not use result values from method you're testing to prepare expected collection. If `unSortedLeads` method has simple error and swaps `FirstName` with `LastName` you will never find such error with this test. Instead you should use literal values.

```cs
[TestMethod()]
public void unSortedLeadsTest()
{
    // read objects from xml
    string xml = "C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/potentialcustomers.xml";
    CustomerLeads target = new CustomerLeads();
    List<CustomerLead> actual = target.unSortedLeads(xml);

    // prepare expected collection
    List<CustomerLead> expected = new List<CustomerLead>()
    {
        new CustomerLead()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName1",
            LastName = "LastName1",
            EmailAddress = "Email@Address1"
        },
        new CustomerLead()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName2",
            LastName = "LastName2",
            EmailAddress = "Email@Address2"
        },
        new CustomerLead()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName3",
            LastName = "LastName3",
            EmailAddress = "Email@Address3"
        }
    };

    // test equality
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

You can read more about implementing `Equals` method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and about unit testing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159340.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AdminUser> adminDetailsExpected = new List<AdminUser>()
{
new AdminUser  {firstName = "test1" , lastName = "test1" , userId = 
"001test1"  },
new AdminUser {firstName = "test2" , lastName = "test2" , userId = 
"002test2"   }
};

 //Act


List<AdminUser> adminDetailsActual = RetrieveAdmin(); // your retrieve logic goes here

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(adminDetailsExpected.Count, adminDetailsActual.Count);  //Test succeeds if the count matches else fails. This count can be used as a work around to test
```