# Unit test - comparing IEnumerable with gener

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, ienumerable

All I want to do here is check that my lambda expression query returns the list of Customers that I expect.

So I've:

1. Got the **actual** result of the query as a list of type Customer (from IEnumerable)
2. Created an **expected** list of type Customer
3. Used CollectionAssert to check each list has the same collection of members
4. But the test fails due to:

[image]

I'm confused. As far as I can see I'm simply comparing 2 lists of the same generic type. What am I missing? Spent about an hour on this trying various casts etc., so any help appreciated.

Thanks

P.S. I'm just playing about with lambdas, linq and unit testing generally, but this is really bugging me!

[image: code]

Comment: Sorry to say that but it's much easier if you post code not the image of code. Unless you want the image of an answer.

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194966/mstest-collectionassert-areequivalent-failed-the-expected-collection-contains

Comment: Apologies. This is my first question. I looked at the "Help" for code posting etiquette but couldn't see anything re images vs cut and paste.

Comment: `new Customer("a") != new Customer("a")`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `FluentAssert` to assert collections. You can use it pretty much for everything, but for collection it is really good.

Otherwise, you could do this kind of assertions.

```
Assert.AreEqual(2, actual.Count);
Assert.AreEqual("jim", actual[0].FirstName); //and more
```

Or you need to have custom equality comparer for your object.